# Что зашифровано в файле?

Tags: стеганография

Дан файл .txt в нем что-то зашифровано стеганографическим методом, нужно найти что. Пробовал менять расширения на .jpeg,.rar,.bnp ничего не нахожу, текст с виду обычный(как всегда)) 
ссылка на файл http://dropmefiles.com/TZTOf

Создал новый текстовый документ и запихнул в него этот текст, вот результат, тут явно что-то есть, только как это достать?)
http://prntscr.com/holyp5

Нашел что в тесте разный код у пробелов, у одних A0 у других 20

Comment: «Пробовал менять расширения на .jpeg,.rar,.bnp» — ну это к стеганографии вообще никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: В текстовом файле всего лишь копипаст теоретических сведений из описания к лабораторной работе в кодировке Windows-1251 и больше ничего. Никаких особенностей, кроме неразрывных пробелов расставленных в полном соответствии с правилами русского языка, здесь нет, и стеганографией здесь не пахнет

Comment: Разве что кто-то захотел запихнуть стеганографию прямо в теоретические сведения, но я сильно сомневаюсь, что такое действительно кто-то делал, тем более текст не уникален и распространён в интернете

Comment: т.к. неразрывные пробелы расставлены всё же произвольно, а не по правилам языка, то в них может быть зашифровано до 90 бит. Из них три байта значащих (95 6d 2a 00 00 ...) с точностью до реверса порядка и/или знака бит. Но ни на какую стандартную сигнатуру они не похожи... В принципе они могли быть по'xor'ены, но впроверять мне это уже лень...

Comment: @Fat-Zer что значит про'xor'eны?

Comment: (и правда, с пробелами по правилам я чёт погорячился, однако я в них тоже ничего не вычитал)

Comment: «новый текстовый документ и запихнул в него этот текст, вот результат» — переконвертировали из кодировки Windows-1251 в кодировку UTF-8. Абсолютно ничего особенного.

Comment: @ДимаСвободин каждый байт «зашифрован» по принципу шифр= byte XOR 0xZZ, где 0xZZ — произвольное число. Но всё равно информации слишком мало, чтобы быть каким-то файлом... это только в случае, если выложена только часть файла.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я попробовал разные пробелы представить как . и - в азбуке морзе. Получилось слово армит с последним символом проблема, был бы я получилось бы что-то осмысленное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле вместо некоторых пробелов были вставлены "пустые символы", сходу их не отличишь, если открыть документ в hex редакторе, можно увидеть что у пробелов код 20 а у символов A0 таким образом была зашифрованы точки и тире в азбуке морзе. Если 2одинаковых символа подряд - тире. Если символы меняются - точки. Итог - SOS.